# Linear Equation with product of variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a problem where I have a matrix of 2*2 and I have a vector of 2 variables. I am trying to find the values of 2 factors. When I solve in python as a linear system of equations. I get values for each factor and when I add those factors I get the required value.

But if I want a formulation in a way where the product of two unknown factors gives a value and I want to find the value for x and y.

For example

```
3x*4y = 19
2x*2y = 23
```

instead of

```
2x+2y = 23
3x+4y = 19
```

How can I solve these equations? where the linear combination is a product instead of sum of two variables.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to be able to generalise to more variables, then you can often convert between a purely multiplicative and a purely additive system via logarithms. For example, if you have $4x \times 2y = 23$ then taking the logarithm of both sides will give you $\log(8 xy) = \log 23 \implies \log x + \log y + \log 8 = \log 23$. Note that if your equations are all of the form $ax \times by = c$, then they'll all reduce to $xy = \frac{c}{ab}$, so you won't be able to solve for $x$ and $y$ individually. However, if you have different *powers* of $x$ and $y$ in different equations, then those exponents will become linear coefficients of $\log x$ and $\log y$ so that you'll be able to solve everything as a linear system.

For example, if you had $x^3 y^2 = 108$ and $x y^3 = 24$, then this would become:

$\begin{eqnarray}\begin{Bmatrix}x^3 y^2 & = & 108 \\ x y^3 & = & 24\end{Bmatrix} & \implies &
\begin{Bmatrix}3 \log x + 2 \log y & = & \log 108 \\ \log x + 3 \log y & = & \log 24 \end{Bmatrix}\end{eqnarray}$

And you can solve this to get $\log x = \frac{3 \log 108 - 2 \log 24}{7} = \log 3$ and $\log y = \frac{3 \log 24 - \log 108}{7} = \log 2$.

Comment: Actually, I have Matrix A of 11*11 and vector b of length 11. I tried finding values of 11 unknowns using z = (A^-1)(b). Which returns me value of 11 unknown factors, so I get a vector with 11 values. 
Now if I add all those values it gives me the value RHS of equality. 
But I want a formulation where product of values on LHS should give the value of RHS of equality.
I don't know how to formulate it as a product of factors